# db2 select add user created text field not in data to query output

Tags: sql, db2

I want to include a user-defined field in the output of my query.  This field is not in the table.  For every row I want myfield to be 'test'.  For the output of "select a, b, myfield" it would be:

```
A .   B .   myfield
1 .   2 .   'test'
3 .   4 .   'test'
```

In oracle this is "select myfield as 'test' ".  In access, this is "select myfield:'test' ".  What is it in db2?

In db2, I saw case statements with user-defined fields, so I tried "select 'test' as myfield" but this didn't work.  I wasn't sure if I needed to use cast.

Answer (score 0):

In any database, you would use:

```
select a, b, 'test' as myfield
from t
```

This is standard SQL and supported by all databases (as far as I know).

Some databases may have additional, alternative methods.  I am not really familiar with `myfield as 'test'` or `myfield:test` in any database.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it worked for me.  I thought I had tried that previously and got an error messsage.